# C# Combine days according to same open and end timings

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to merge days with similar opening hours of a store together. For example, if we have:

```
Mon 9am-5pm
Tue 9am-5pm
Wed 9am-5pm
Thu 8am-6pm
Fri 8am-6pm
Sat 10am-2pm
```

I want the code to simplify it to:

```
Mon-Wed 9am-5pm
Thu-Fri 8am-6pm
Sat     10am-2pm
Sun     -
```

How do I do this without a long list of if/else.

Comment: Where is the data coming from?

Comment: And in what format? A list of strings, etc? How does your code look and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Fred I have the data in table. With three Columns. `DayName`,`From`,`To`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with minimal explicit conditional logic. The strategy is to: (1) convert the data to objects; (2) perform the merge based on the objects created in (1):

```
  // mimic data from databasse
  var days = new[] {"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};
  var openTime = new[] {"9am", "9am", "9am", "8am", "8am", "10am"};
  var closeTime = new[] {"5pm", "5pm", "5pm", "6pm", "6pm", "2pm"};

  // lookup of day code to DayOfWeek enum
  var dayOfWeekMap = Enum.GetNames(typeof(DayOfWeek))
    .ToDictionary(
      x => x.Substring(0, 3),
      x => (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), x));

  // convert data to objects
  var dayStoreHours =
    Enumerable.Range(0, days.Count())
      .Select(idx => new StoreHours {
        DayOfWeek = dayOfWeekMap[days[idx]],
        OpenTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
          openTime[idx],
          "htt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
          .TimeOfDay,
        CloseTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
          closeTime[idx],
          "htt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
          .TimeOfDay
      })
      .ToDictionary(x => x.DayOfWeek, x => x);

  // merge consecutive days if open and close time match
  var mergedStoreHours = new HashSet<MergedStoreHours>();

  var currentMergedHours = default(MergedStoreHours);

  Enum.GetNames(typeof(DayOfWeek))
    .Select(x => (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), x))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(dow => {

      if (!dayStoreHours.ContainsKey(dow)) {
        // there are not hours recorded for the current day
        // create an entry for this day with identical open and close time
        mergedStoreHours.Add(
          new MergedStoreHours { 
            FirstDayOfWeek = dow, 
            LastDayOfWeek = dow
        });
        return;
      }

      var currentDayStoreHours = dayStoreHours[dow];

      if (currentMergedHours != default(MergedStoreHours) &&
          currentDayStoreHours.OpenTime == currentMergedHours.OpenTime &&
          currentDayStoreHours.CloseTime == currentMergedHours.CloseTime
        ) {
        // extend the merged hours to the current day
        currentMergedHours.LastDayOfWeek = dow;
      } else {
        currentMergedHours = new MergedStoreHours {
          FirstDayOfWeek =  dow, 
          LastDayOfWeek = dow,
          OpenTime = currentDayStoreHours.OpenTime,
          CloseTime = currentDayStoreHours.CloseTime
        };
      }

      mergedStoreHours.Add(currentMergedHours);
    });

  // order in increasing day of the week, placing sunday last
  var orderMergedHours = mergedStoreHours
    .OrderBy(x => x.FirstDayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ? 8 : x.FirstDayOfWeek.GetHashCode())
    .ToList();
```

The object model to represent the hours for a store and the merged hours is:

```
  public class StoreHours {
    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan OpenTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan CloseTime { get; set; }
  }

  public class MergedStoreHours {
    public DayOfWeek FirstDayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public DayOfWeek LastDayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan OpenTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan CloseTime { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
      var day = FirstDayOfWeek != LastDayOfWeek ? FirstDayOfWeek + "-" + LastDayOfWeek : FirstDayOfWeek.ToString();
      var timeRange = OpenTime != CloseTime ? OpenTime + "-" + CloseTime : "-";

      return day + " " + timeRange;
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Just a comment the ordering is not working at all `.OrderBy(x => x.FirstDayOfWeek)`. Sunday is always listed on top.

Comment: The conventional ordering of days in the US is to start the week with Sunday. The DayOfWeek enum is ordered based on that convention. The ordering can easily be altered to place Sunday last like so:       var `orderMergedHours = mergedStoreHours.OrderBy(x => x.FirstDayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ? 8 : x.FirstDayOfWeek.GetHashCode()).ToList();`

Answer (score 2):

Just putting in my two cents:

```
void Main()
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("DayName");
    dt.Columns.Add("From");
    dt.Columns.Add("To");

    AddDay(dt, "Mon", "9am", "5pm");
    AddDay(dt, "Tue", "9am", "5pm");
    AddDay(dt, "Wed", "9am", "5pm");
    AddDay(dt, "Thu", "8am", "6pm");
    AddDay(dt, "Fri", "8am", "6pm");
    AddDay(dt, "Sat", "10am", "2pm");
    AddDay(dt, "Sun", "", "");

    var combined = GetCombinedOpeningHours(dt);
    Console.WriteLine(combined);
}

void AddDay(DataTable dt, string dayName, string fromTime, string toTime)
{
    var row = dt.NewRow();
    row["DayName"] = dayName;
    row["From"] = fromTime;
    row["To"] = toTime;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}

Dictionary<string,string> GetCombinedOpeningHours(DataTable dt)
{
    (dt.Columns.Add("OpeningHours")).Expression = "From+'-'+To";

    var groupedByOpeningHours = from day in dt.AsEnumerable() 
                                group day by day.Field<string>("OpeningHours") into g 
                                select g;

    var combined = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    foreach(var grp in groupedByOpeningHours)
    {
        var firstDay = grp.FirstOrDefault().Field<string>("DayName");
        var lastDay = grp.LastOrDefault().Field<string>("DayName");

        var key = (firstDay == lastDay) ? firstDay : firstDay + "-" + lastDay;
        if (!combined.ContainsKey(key))
            combined.Add(key, grp.FirstOrDefault().Field<string>("OpeningHours"));
    }
    return combined;
}
```